# Set Button at reached point in progress bar in android

Tags: android

I am working on Android application. I am using progressBar component inside my application and I trying to put small button on the reached point in the progressBar. but all my tries fails to do this

The code of my progressBar.

```
       <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarStartScreen"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:minHeight="14dip"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customprogressbar"
         >     
   </ProgressBar>
```

And my button code is

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/setttingButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:text="Reached Point"
        android:textColor="#d85546"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This image to describe what I mean.

[image]

Please There are any one to help me to put the button on the reached pointed in Progress bar.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do exactly? There are ways to dynamically place a button where you want, but depending on what your actual goal is, that might not even be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this work around

```
@Override  
protected void onProgressUpdate() {  
    //Do something...
}
```

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but I'm quite positive that when the user touches the progress bar, it will move slightly.

This will work best when you set `progressBar.setMax()` to a high number.

Comment: Thinks for replay, But the problem here I can defined the position x and position y for reached point.

Comment: No one know how to get the x and y position of reach point in progress Bar ?